# Verify Data Type with MVC

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a table with 10 columns that stores user documents. 1 of them is for image and others are for pdf files. I just store data. No name no extension etc. For example Column10 is for PDF so i try to show it in applicaion as PDF by default. I just control if it's null.

I wonder about can i verify data is really image or pdf in that column before showing link in application?

Btw, I use MVC 5 and EF 6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code required to do this would be quite complex, much easier to store the file type in the table.

Comment: For example user can change file extension before upload. Is this uncontrollable ?

Btw, this is not a big requirement for me but just wondered...

Comment: A regular user will not intentionally change the extension before upload. And there is no easy way to verify if a file is an image or pdf. And if your requirements change in the future to also store txt, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, etc. then the time required in verifying is not worth it.